# How to group numeric values containing missing data into bins for counting in python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, histogram

I have a series of integer values with missing data in a dataframe (Clean) that I want to bin into larger integer groups and then count those bins (like producing a histogram). It is a large dataset so I don't want to subset by removing the NaNs. I have this:

```
TLag
NaN
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
20
22
```

And I want this:

```
LagBin  Count
0       4
10      5
20      2
```

I tried using the pd.cut:

```
tbins=np.arange(0,3600,10)
Clean['LagBin']=pd.cut(Clean['TLag'],bins=tbins,right=True, labels=None,           retbins=False, precision=0, include_lowest=True)
```

But this returns LagBin values as a range, and since I ultimately want to plot this I really want the bins to be numeric.  Also, when I tried to count using the groupby function (rx is another grouping variable that will be in the multiindex):

```
Hist=Clean.groupby(level=('rx','LagBin'))
Hist.count('LagBin')
```

But this returns an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer
```

So I thought I could just convert the Lag value to integer bins using a simple transformation:

```
Clean['LagBin']=Clean.TLag/10
Clean['LagBin']=(int(Clean.LagBin))*10
```

I also tried the hist() function--neither one works, yielding this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

This seems like a tremendously simple exercise, which should be straightforward.  What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand your desired output.  Shouldn't there be 5 in your LagBin 10 group?  (10,12,14,16,18).  Or, alternatively, if your intervals are closed-upper, 5 in the 0 group?

Comment: I want to bin into bins of 10  (0,10,20...3600).  Ultimately this is about producing a density function that I want to do further manipulations on.  The 10-size group is arbitrary and something I want to be able to shift as occasion permits.  OK I understand the quesion now--so I guess I am not really concerned whether the 10 is inclusive or not.  Usually I do this by dividing by 10 , taking the integer, and then multiplying that integer by 10, so that I think is  closed upper, right?  10/10 is 1*10 is 10, so 10 goes into the next bin.

Comment: So your `Count` column of [4,4,2] is incorrect given the data you've shown?

Comment: Sigh.  Yes.  It should be 4,5,2.  I will fix that

Comment: As I see it the issue seems to be with the NaN's.  I am a SAS and Access user and new to Python and R and am having trouble wrapping my mind around tasks that are straighforward in sql (I don't want to use sql here mostly because I am trying to learn, and the dataframe is 12 million records X 17 columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got the right idea, more or less, and are simply being caught up on syntax.  For example, we can use the divide-by-ten-multiply-by-ten trick to add a `LagBin` column, and then `groupby`-`count` on that:

```
In [21]: Clean["LagBin"] = (Clean["TLag"]//10)*10

In [22]: Clean
Out[22]: 
    TLag  LagBin
0    NaN     NaN
1      2       0
2      4       0
3      6       0
4      8       0
5     10      10
6     12      10
7     14      10
8     16      10
9     18      10
10    20      20
11    22      20

In [23]: Clean.groupby("LagBin", as_index=False).count()
Out[23]: 
   LagBin  TLag
0       0     4
1      10     5
2      20     2
```

Note that I've used `//` for truncating division so that both `2//10 == 0` and `2.0//10 == 0` (instead of `0.2`).

If you'd prefer to be even closer to exactly your desired output, you could either rename `TLag` there or group the column itself:

```
In [46]: Clean["TLag"].groupby(Clean["LagBin"]).count().reset_index(name="Count")
Out[46]: 
   LagBin  Count
0       0      4
1      10      5
2      20      2
```

Comment: Perfect--the first solution worked just fine.  I don't understand the purpose of .reset_index() though.  Can you clarify?  It throws an error when I run it...my actual code is more complex and the dataframe includes a multi-index already.  Do I need to add LagBin to the multi-index?

Comment: In the second example, without `as_index=False`, the group keys (in this case the bins) are used as the index for the resulting dataframe.  I wanted that index to be promoted back up to a real column, and give the resulting column the name `Count`.

Comment: More about the multi-index: the TLag comes from different receivers (fieldname 'rx'), and I really want to group by rx.  So this is what I have entered:    Clean['LagBin']=(Clean.TLag//10)*10

arrays = [Clean.rx,Clean.LagBin]                      # Define arrays object, which contains both levels of the multi-index
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names = ['rx','LagBin'])            # declare multi level index
Clean.index = index

Comment: @TheodoreCastro-Santos: you're still relatively new here :-) so I should probably warn you that comment sections aren't really how we handle follow-up questions.  If you have a separate question, form a small example that people can copy and paste to test with sample input and desired output, and open a new question.  Plus that way more people see it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.    But it is a follow-up....so do I add this as an edit to the original post?

Comment: @TheodoreCastro-Santos: no, because that question was answered.  SO works via discrete questions and answers, not like a forum where there's a back-and-forth until a problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

try **labels** in the function **pd.cut** .

```
tlag = np.arange(0, 30, 2)
tbins = np.arange(0, 100, 10)
pd.value_counts(np.cut(tlag, tbins, labels = tbins[:-1]))
```

the output is:

```
Out[136]: 
0     5
10    5
20    4
```